# Configure Nginx Ingress Upstream Vhost with Wildcard Subdomain

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, amazon-eks, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress

I have an EKS cluster that has the [ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) controller deployed.

I'm using nginx to proxy to external services, but was hoping to deploy a single Ingress object to handle routing across multiple hosts. However, the upstream-vhost seems to only work with a single fully-qualified host name.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: httpbin-foobar
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: httpbin-svc
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
spec:
  externalName: httpbin.upstream.example.com
  type: ExternalName
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: httpbin2-foobar
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: httpbin2-svc
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
spec:
  externalName: httpbin2.upstream.example.com
  type: ExternalName
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-tls
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: '/'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost: 'httpbin.upstream.example.com'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: https
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: 'true'
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - '*.downstream.example.com'
      secretName: downstream-cert
  rules:
    - host: 'httpbin.downstream.example.com'
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: httpbin-foobar
                port:
                  number: 443
    - host: 'httpbin2.downstream.example.com'
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: httpbin2-foobar
                port:
                  number: 443
```

The example above works for both routes, however they both are routed to `httpbin.upstream.example.com` due to the static `upstream-vhost`
I was hoping there was a way to have it match on `*.downstream.example.com`, then I can freely add new host rules in the Ingress and have them be routed to the correct place.

If it isn't possible, that's ok as I'll just have to create a new `Ingress` per route, but ideally I could squish them all in to a single Ingress.